# Problem in retrieving the out parameter of a mysql stored procedure through php script

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

Hi I have a simple MYSQL stored procedure which has an IN (int) and an OUT (int) parameters.
I am calling the stored procedure from a PHP script.

Stored Procedure code:

```
  DELIMITER $$
  USE `testing`$$

  DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test_sp_inout_params`$$

  CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test_sp_inout_params`(IN username VARCHAR(30), OUT user_id INT)
  BEGIN
   INSERT INTO users (`name`) VALUES (username);
   SET user_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
  END$$

 DELIMITER ;
```

I am able to run the stored procedure from mysql query window with:

```
 CALL test_sp_inout_params('TestName', @user_id);
 SELECT @user_id
```

But from PHP script I am geting errors.. :(

```
    mysqli_query($conn, "CALL test_sp_inout_params('surya', @user_id)");
    $rs = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT @user_id");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);
    var_dump($row);
```

[EDITED]
The above PHP script executed perfectly, when it is running individually.
But I have another stored procedure.. and when I am calling that before the above php-script, I am geting that sort of warning message.
So, the script I am using is (before the above mentioned php script):

```
    $rs1 = mysqli_query($conn, "CALL test_sp_no_params()");
    $arr = array();
    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs1))
        $arr[] = $row1;
```

What is the problem when I am calling the second stored procedure?

Can anyone help me out please!

Thanks in advance,
SuryaPavan

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in ..........

var_dump($row) ==> NULL

Answer (score 0):

I have recently been having troubles with MySQLI as well. I am using MySQLI::multi_query but I would assume that this may be a solution for you as well. After you call the query, try using this function and let me know if it brings back what you're expecting. Seeing as you're only doing a single query instead of a multi_query I'm sure you could trim some of the fat off of this function as well.

```
public function getResultSets() {
    $retVal = array();
    do {
        if ($result = $this->mysqli->store_result())
            $retVal[] = $result;
    } while ($this->mysqli->next_result());
    return $retVal;
}
```

I will say, however, that a stored procedure call will not return anything. If you would like it to then you have to set out parameters and pass them along. For instance, if I have a stored procedure with 2 ins and 2 outs, I would pass this into the MySQLI::multi_query (the multi_query part of it means you can specify multiple queries to pass along the same way you would in mysql workbench).

```
$thisGuy = new MySQLI(inputParamsHere);
$retVal = $thisGuy->multi_query("CALL myDB.storedProc($var1, $var2, @return1, @return2); select @return1 as firstValue, @return2 as secondValue;");
if ($retVal) getResultSets();
```

getResultSets() will then return an array that contains the results of each query within it (so long as there is something in the result set, the initial stored procedure call returns nothing and therefore there is an empty result set within the mysqli object that we dispose of it in the function).

Comment: Hmm if that is the case then I apologize. I just started working with this myself.

Basically you can copy whatever you write in MySQL workbench into a multi_query and it will run it the same way. What you wrote above, "CALL test_sp_no_params(); CALL test_sp_inout_params('surya', @user_id); SELECT @user_id;");, will in fact call test_sp_no_params followed by test_sp_inout_params followed by your select statement. It is executed sequentially from my experience.

Comment: Okay, Thanks yaar for the reply. The issue got temporarily solved by using mysqli_multi_query($conn, "CALL test_sp_no_params(); CALL test_sp_inout_params('surya', @user_id); SELECT @user_id;");. But it is not always the case to do multi query right? I want those stored procedures to be executed individually one after another :( Also, you said I will say, however, that a stored procedure call will not return anything. If the stored-procedure is just only " `SELECT * FROM users` ", then even though if there is no OUT parameter also, the stored-procedure-call returns RESULT-SET.

Comment: Also, if you are looking to only execute one at a time (I have not done this so don't quote me on it) I think you can just use mysqli_query and pass in the single line query that you want to run. The difference between the two from my understanding is that multi_query runs multiple queries as delimited by semi-colons. Retrieving the results should take the same format.